# Tesseract.js doesn't work for arabic language?

Tags: node.js, ocr, tesseract, arabic

I'm using tesseract.js with nodeJs to recognize arabic text from an image
but, unfortunately, it gives me a text which is not compliant with the text of the input image.

the input:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/in7VS.png)

the output:
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLmRw.png)

```
var tesseract = require('tesseract.js')
var request = require('request')
var fs = require('fs')
var util = require('util');
var path = 'C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/projet'
var log_file = fs.createWriteStream(path + '/arab.txt', {flags : 'w'});
var log_stdout = process.stdout;
var filename = 'capture.PNG'
tesseract.create({ langPath: "ara.cube.fold"  })
       .recognize(filename, 'ara')
       .progress(function  (p) { console.log('progress', p)  })
       .catch(err => console.error(err))
       .then(function (result) {
    console.log = function(result) {
      log_file.write(util.format(result) + '\n');
      log_stdout.write(util.format(result) + '\n');
     };
    console.log(result.text)
    process.exit(0)
})
```

any solution please!!

Comment: Did you find a solution?